# Windows 10 booting stucks on logo. Hard restart helps

Tags: windows-10

So there was an update. I hate this thing pn windpws 10, because it is unexpected. I turned off updates somehow some time ago and then wondows turned it on automatically.

So, after an update, I have a strange problem - turning on my pc, windows boot stucks at a logo screen (black with Win logo). Hard restart (via the button) helps all the time, but the problem still exists. Also teying to restart from the windows (Win - Restart) won't get me to this problem.

Comment: Download latest ISO using media creation tool and reinstall, keeping files. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Can you mention the name of that update? You can get the name from update history.

Comment: @user52599 KB2267602 is the last one

Comment: Try updating Windows I think (not sure) it is a bug related to that update

Answer (score 1):

For individual, retail machines, updates cannot be disable and will turn themselves ON. No way to stop this. Business Enterprise can use Long Term Service editions to control updates, but most users must update.

No issue here on fully up to date machines.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run both:

`dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

and

`SFC /SCANNOW`

Now update BIOS, Chipset (if it exists on your computer), Video and Power drivers. Use the Manufacturer's support site to update all drivers.

Restart, run Windows Updates again and check the operation of your computer.

Follow up note:  Application software (Office, Adobe, and so on) needs to be modern and up to date. Some people use old, out of support software thinking it should run on Windows 10

Comment: Error: 87 DISM doesn't recognize the command-line option AND

Comment: `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and `SFC /SCANNOW` are different commands.

Comment: Op, sorry. My bad

Comment: @John Since he turns it off with a press button, wouldn't it be better to check the hard disk also, before he does any more writing to the hard disk(s)?, thanks.

Comment: Certainly it is worth checking the Drive and doing all hardware tests as well

Comment: I've already checked my hard drive - everything's okay. I push the hard restart button, not the turn-off button

Comment: Did all that - no errors, all fixed. But the problem still persists

Comment: You may now be at the point where you need to back up your data and email and re-install Windows

Comment: Unable to revert Windows update. And the next Windows update did not solve the problem, unfortunately :(

Comment: @John if the computer does't boot, how can you `open cmd.exe`?